# Register form doesn't work

Tags: forms, cakephp

I got `RegisterController.php` and inside of it I got:

```
class RegisterController extends AppController {
    public $name = 'Register';
    public $components = array('Session');

    public function index() {
        if ($this->request->is('account')) {
           // if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
                echo "got it";
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been saved.');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
           // }
        }
    }
}
```

My `/View/Register/index.tcp` file:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Account');
    echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');
    $options = array(
        'label' => 'Register',
        'class' => 'submit'
    );
    echo $this->Form->end($options);
?>
```

And my `/Model/Account.php` file:

```
<?php
class Account extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Account';
    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'Can not be empty.'
            ),
            'minLength' => array(
                'rule' => array('minLength', '8'),
                'message' => 'Min. 8 chars.'
            )
        )
    );
}
?>
```

The problem is that, I'm clicking on the submit button, and nothing happends. It should at least check for validation.

Where is the error?

Comment: Have you checked the created HTML output, if the form has an action?

Comment: @entek
#edit Yes , the form has an action, the page just reload when I click the submit button.

Comment: Who downrated it without leaving a comment? Lul.

Comment: @entek Idk who downvotes, that was not me. But anyway, the script still doesn't work.There is an `action` attribute on form , but it still only refresh the page.

Comment: Please post the generated HTML form.

Comment: NVM, I've found this: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html
//Accepted your answer, thanks for the help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work if you add the action in options:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Account', array('action' => 'your/url'));
```